# eslint error while writting and running test units in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, npm, eslint

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uymiu.png)

The following error is occurring when running tests on my code.

```
rror [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/rules/no-warning-comments' is not defined by "exports" in /data/credenceInternship/iwf-cli/node_modules/eslint/package.json
at throwExportsNotFound (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:290:9)
at packageExportsResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:513:3)
at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:432:36)
at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:472:31)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:867:27)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
at require (/data/credenceInternship/iwf-cli/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (/data/credenceInternship/iwf-cli/node_modules/eslint-plugin-unicorn/rules/expiring-todo-comments.js:5:18)
at Module._compile (/data/credenceInternship/iwf-cli/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.